# Steam API - Get contents of CSGO Storage Units

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am attempting to get the contents of a Steams users inventory, specifically CSGO items.

The API request I send is:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{STEAM_USER_ID}/inventory/json/730/2
```

It retrieves the the contents of a steam user's inventory, including CSGOs Storage Units, but not the contents of the Storage Units.

Here is part of the return payload relating to a Storage Unit:

```
{
      appid: 730,
      classid: '3605067702',
      instanceid: '3726741626',
      currency: 0,
      background_color: '',
      icon_url: '-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxqAhWSVieErT9hpbQAF8ncFNU4O3xe15l1afJcjhHu4jlxNiPlqWiZLmIx28DvYthhO6K88GN3g',
      icon_url_large: '-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxqAhWSVjvS-W_0MqdAFwiJAdS7-v9eFVm16WZdWkXtYWwxdjTw_PwauLQxTkJ6cd3jrvArcLlhlOwU2JlOg',
      descriptions: [Array],
      tradable: 0,
      fraudwarnings: [Array],
      name: 'Storage Unit',
      name_color: 'D2D2D2',
      type: 'Base Grade Tool',
      market_name: 'Storage Unit',
      market_hash_name: 'Storage Unit',
      commodity: 1,
      market_tradable_restriction: 7,
      marketable: 0,
      tags: [Array]
    }
```

Is there a way to obtain the details of the contents of CSGO Storage Units via the Steam API? Many thanks